# Firefox instances do not work with Fiddler on Windows 8.1 and 7 when create a session with SeleniumGrid

Tags: firefox, windows-7, windows-8.1, fiddler, selenium-grid

I am working on a project to test a Web Application. To do that, I have 3 VMs. Each Vms has a different version of Windows : 7, 8.1 and 10.

I need to test this app against Firefox and I use Fiddler to capture the traffic.

If I open fiddler and then open Firefox and navigate to the App, all is OK.

However, if I open fiddler and then open a session on Firefox with Selenium, I obtain a warning window on Firefox which says :

> Warning : Potential Security Risk Ahead
>
> Error : SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER

This issue occurs only for Windows 7 and 8.1. The same configuration is used for all versions of Windows (7, 8.1 and 10). The configuration of Firefox for Fiddler is applied (https://www.telerik.com/blogs/configuring-firefox-for-fiddler).

My version of Firefox is 69.0.1 (64 bit).

Is there a solution for this ?